# Lodash _.sortBy based on created date and time

Tags: javascript, lodash, angular7

```js
let notesInfo = []

if (_.isArray(result)) {
  console.log(result, '-----------');
  notesInfo = _.sortBy(result, ['modifiedDate']);
} else {
  notesInfo = result;
}

console.log(notesInfo)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

I am using this code to display the notes based on created date and time. The note which added latest should come on top using sortBy menthod of lodash. How to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to sort them in descending order or only put the most recent on top, the rest in ascending order underneath?

Comment: I want to display the most recent on top the rest in ascending

Comment: I have added lodash to the snippet. Please add a sample of `result` to create a [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have the most recent item first but the rest in ascending order, then you can just sort normally in ascending order. Since the last element would be the most recent, you can then rotate it to the front of the array with [`Array#pop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) and [`Array#unshift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift):

```js
let result = [
  { modifiedDate: "2019-02-01", name: "february" },
  { modifiedDate: "2019-04-01", name: "april" },
  { modifiedDate: "2019-01-01", name: "january" },
  { modifiedDate: "2019-03-01", name: "march" }
];

//sort ascending
let notesInfo = _.sortBy(result, ['modifiedDate']);

//take the most recent (last)
var lastElement = notesInfo.pop();

//place it first
notesInfo.unshift(lastElement);

console.log(notesInfo);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

If you want the items in descending order, then you should use [`_.orderBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#orderBy) instead of `_.sortBy`:

```js
let result = [
  { modifiedDate: "2019-02-01", name: "february" },
  { modifiedDate: "2019-04-01", name: "april" },
  { modifiedDate: "2019-01-01", name: "january" },
  { modifiedDate: "2019-03-01", name: "march" }
];

//sort descending
let notesInfo = _.orderBy(result, ['modifiedDate'], ['desc']);

console.log(notesInfo);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: but in this case, If I add 3 notes one after the other, it is displaying like note 3, note 1 then note 2

Comment: That's what you wanted, right? Most recent on top, then the rest in ascending order, so `3 -> 1 -> 2` should be the correct based on this.

Comment: My apologies for misleading, actually it should display 3 -> 2 -> 1

Comment: I got a solution for this, I have updated the code as this.notesInfo = _.sortBy(result, ['modifiedDate']).reverse();

Comment: @User I added a solution for descending order. You don't need `reverse`, you can just use `orderBy` from Lodash.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that is your data:

```
 var result = [{
      name: "Mango",
      modifiedDate: "Mon Oct 10 2019 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)"
    }, {
      name: "Banana",
      modifiedDate: "Sun Oct 9 2019 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)"
    }, {
      name: "Kivi",
      modifiedDate: "Sat Oct 8 2019 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)"
    }];
```

You can achieve it without lodash by native `Array.prototype.sort()`

```
result.sort(function compare(a, b) {
  var dateA = new Date(a.modifiedDate);
  var dateB = new Date(b.modifiedDate);
  return dateA - dateB;
});
```

Or with lodash

```
output = _.sortBy(result, function(dateObj) {
  return new Date(dateObj.modifiedDate);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let notesInfo = []

if (_.isArray(result)) {
  console.log(result, '-----------');
  notesInfo = _.sortBy(result, ['modifiedDate']).reverse();
} else {
  notesInfo = result;
}

console.log(notesInfo)
```

This works as expected. Thanks